# What happens when a timer thread goes to sleep

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer, sleep

```
static readonly System.Timers.Timer _timer = new System.Timers.Timer();

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    _timer.Interval = 1000;
    _timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(Timer_Elapsed);
    _timer.Start();

    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
    Console.ReadKey();
}

static void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);
    Thread.Sleep(600000); // 10 minutes
    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);
}
```

What happens to the timer thread with such a long sleep? Does it get back to thread pool or we end up many sleeping threads?

Comment: "What happens when a timer thread goes to sleep?" - you can stop reading "Bunny Goes Bananas!" to it! ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sleeping threads will return to the thread pool, but **only after the sleep ends**. A thread pool has a maximum number of threads, that means you could run out of threads to use, because all of them will be sleeping.

**EDIT:**

ThreadPool docs:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.getmaxthreads.aspx

Comment: But under `Task Manager` thread count of this application is 30 and doesn't change over time.

Comment: That is because of thread pool maximum threads. As all threads are sleeping, new requests for threads remain queued until thread pool threads become available. Look at documentation for ThreadPool. I have edited the answer to include the link.